# In N2CMS, can you disable the prompt to 'Update links leading to' the item you just edited?

Tags: n2cms, n2

I am using N2CMS to manage the content of my site without using the page routing from N2. Hence when I edit a piece of content, it's quite useless when N2 asks me: "Update links leading to..." "Add permanent redirect at previous URL?". Can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting Page into Part is inherently bad idea. It may be temporary fix for the problem you have, but it will bounce back at you in a bad way.

Instead, you can do this

- Turn LinkTracker off in web.config

  ```
  linkTracker enabled="false" permanentRedirectEnabled="false"
  ```
- Copy CommandFactory.cs from N2 Source into your solution, and rename it to MyCommandFactory.cs.
  Add Service replacement attribute

  ```
  [Service(typeof(ICommandFactory), Replaces = typeof(CommandFactory))]
  ```

In a constructor, change this line

```
updateReferences = new MyUpdateReferencesCommand();
```

- Write your own empty Update reference command class

  ```
  public class MyUpdateReferencesCommand : UpdateReferencesCommand
  {
      public override void Process(CommandContext state)
      {
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: In my project, I am not using any of the N2 routing or templating. I have written my own wrapper classes to get the content from the N2 object model and place it in existing pages. It seems to make no difference whether I use [PageDefinition] or [PartDefinition] apart from the interface used to edit them (actually [PartDefinition] is more appropriate interface for the content in question). Can you tell me what problems I might face in the future going down this route?

Comment: Well, that depends on extent of your replacements. If you replaced most of the functionalities of N2 with your own, then you will probably have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the source code, N2 expects always to show you the "Update links leading to..." page if the ContentItem is a Page (i.e. [PageDefinition] attribute or .IsPage = true) and the address has been updated. The solution in our case was to make the 'page' in question into a 'part' using [PartDefinition].